# Why is the window resize animation running slowly?

Tags: graphic-drivers, window-management, performance

I'm running elementary on my desktop with Nvidia GTX460 graphic card and enough hardware power to run everything smoothly.

Therefore it is very strange that when I change the size of my window, animation is very laggy and not fluent. I would think it might be related to graphics drivers, but I tested all of the available, with same results.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have tweak installed?

Comment: Could you get into more detail of your system? How much RAM do you have and which processor and screen setup / resolution are you using?

Comment: @shyam
yes - tweak is installed

Comment: @quassy

My system specs are:

AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 630 Processor
4gb RAM
GeForce GTX 460
Resolution: 1920x1080

And to be more precise: The laggy animations are mostly only those when you manually enlarge or reduce the window size, NOT when clicking on mini- or maximize. Interesting though: My Firefox windows is not laggy ... but all others :)

Comment: Does it happen with a custom theme? If yes, that might be the reason.

Comment: @quassy No, I do not use any custom theme. It also had the same effect without the use of Tweak.